# What to test with JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

**Premise**
I am about to try my hand for the first time in testing a university project in which I was thrown without the slightest experience, finding myself in front of a gigantic problem:
*How and what should I test*

Mine is a simple app that communicates with a movie database and has an MVVM structure.

These are my packages:
activities,
adapters (for recycler views),
fragments,
models,
repositories,
request,
response,
utils,
viewmodels

My question is should i test everything? For example do activities or fragments have to be tested with Espresso or also with JUnit?

Answer (score 0):

You should test everything that contains logic. Since UI components and things like database/filesystem/network access are usually hard and/or slow to test, you should make sure that the logic is not in these components. Just from the name of your packages it is hard to tell which need testing.

Rule of thumb: Does it contain loops, condition and other nonlinear code? Test it.

Comment: For example, to check if a text field contains a certain text string, we intervene with express UI testing. If I want to verify that a method is returning me an object, I intervene with JUnit. Correct?

Comment: That's the gist of it.